# Can I use my own template for a view mode?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm creating a cusom module that loads a node  through a `view_builder`. However, none of the available `view_mode` display the elements like I'd like them to be, so I'm about to create my own view mode. However, I have parsed quite a few tutorials about view_builders, but none talked about using a custom template (or I missed it)

So, is it possible to use your own template, and how do you do so?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to create a template in your theme, you can use node--nodetype--viewmode.html.twig . (two dashes between each part).

To use it in your custom module, you'd have to use hook_theme_registry_alter to change the path that it looks in for that theme hook.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['node__nodetype__viewmode']['path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates/';
}
```

I don't really see the value of moving it into a custom module though.  It's a standard to keep custom templates in the theme.

Comment: This is a specific need, the project I work on is so big that putting in in the theme directory slows everything down. However thank you for your answer, I got to try it and it worked pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

When calling the view method, the second argument is the name of a view mode:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilderInterface.php/function/EntityViewBuilderInterface%3A%3Aview/8.2.x

Pass in the machine name of the view mode you want to use.

Example:

```
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
$output = $view_builder->view($node, 'my_view_mode');
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but my question is more about if I can use my own template as a `view_mode`

Comment: I don't understand what that means, but if you create a new View Mode under Admin > Structure > Display Modes, configure the node display with that view mode, you can certainly then define a `node--node_type--view_mode.html.twig` template. Thats basically using your 'own' template. From here, you can preprocess and add variables or whatever you want and output them in that twig template.

Comment: Oh, okay, do you know if I can put this `node--node_type-view_mode.html.twig` anywhere?

Comment: I've never tried it from the module level, but you can try and see what happens.